# On click JS function syntax Map marker

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am trying to call a JS function on a button placed in the info window of map marker and pass the SFDC id to it, But the JS is giving me a syntax error. Here's my piece of code-

```
for(var i=0, j=mapData.length; i<j; i++){
   //Add marker for each point
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(mapData[i].lat, mapData[i].lng);
    var markercolor= mapData[i].markerText;
    console.log(markercolor);

    if (markercolor.startsWith("00Q")){
      var contentString = '<a href="/'+ mapData[i].markerText + '" target="_blank">'+mapData[i].name+'</a>'+'<br/>'+
                           mapData[i].Street+',' +'<br/>'+ mapData[i].City +',' +'<br/>'+ mapData[i].State +'<br/>'+
                          "<input type='submit' id='butSubmit' value='Edit' onclick='openVFWindow("+mapData[i].markerText+")' >";
     }

       addMarker({position: myLatlng, markerText: contentString , color: markercolor});
 }
```

JS function-

```
function openVFWindow(markerid) {
   console.log('iddddddddd'+markerid);
}
```

So markerText has the Salesforce id of the record and its getting populated correctly. When I click on the console, the error is shown as

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token with the error line -openVFWindow(00Qg000000CcEezEAF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to missing string markers around the parameters in your onclick

Your code reads

```
onclick='openVFWindow("+mapData[i].markerText+")'
```

which renders as

```
onclick='openVFWindow(someId)'
```

JS then assumes `someId` is a variable, and not a value. Your should wrap the value in doublequotes, so that JS understands it is a literal. it looks like this while rendered:

```
onclick='openVFWindow("someId")'
```

You can achieve that by changing your code to the following

```
onclick='openVFWindow(\""+mapData[i].markerText+"\")'
```

The escaped doublequotes will render as regular doublequotes in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the Id in quotes. It shouldn't be `openVFWindow(00Qg000000CcEezEAF)`, it should be `openVFWindow("00Qg000000CcEezEAF")`. Or you could use single quotes if you like.

Change:

```
"<input ... onclick='openVFWindow("+mapData[i].markerText+")' >"
```

To:

```
"<input ... onclick='openVFWindow(\""+mapData[i].markerText+"\")' >"
```